# gulp+browserify - get file name/line on error

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify

I use gulp to build my browserified files, problem is that when i have a syntax error the build fails with a generic message:

> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token

As you can see it's impossible to understand which file caused the error.

Is there a way to get the file name/line that caused the error?

Answer (score -1):

Consider using gulp-debug https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-debug it is a plugin that help you see what files are run through your gulp pipeline